# Changing a bootstrap template that already has a div container and div row

Tags: html, css, templates

I am attempting to use a basic bootstrap template, I have added a:

```
<div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>This is the text I would like to align left</p>. 
    </div>
</div>
```

However the bootstrap template I have used has text center align - how do I add a rule just for this paragraph to align left ? (where and what would it be called?)
I should add that I have one css document for the website and can't add to the main  class - I need to make a rule just for this area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your row div also **"text-left"** class should be used there like this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="text-left">This is the text I would like to align left</p>. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <p class = "text-left">This is the text I would like to align left</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use this it will align the left side. (class = "text-left" on the paragraph tag).